# Raspberry PI + Wiegand RFID

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have problem with my Wiegand RFID reader (26bit). I have write simple Java app and everything seems fine. But after 10 reads for example, it starts to shift bits. Is RPi Raspbian to slow for Wiegand time protocol?

Here is sample code and output

```
package classes;


import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
public class Test {


    public static char[] s = new char[10000];
    static int bits = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        // provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down
        // resistor enabled
        final GpioPinDigitalInput pin0 = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP);

        final GpioPinDigitalInput pin1 = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP);

        System.out.println("PINs ready");
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {

                    if (pin0.isLow()) { // D1 on ground?
                        s[bits++] = '0';
                        while (pin0.isLow()) {

                        }

                    }

                    if (pin1.isLow()) { // D1 on ground?
                        s[bits++] = '1';
                        while (pin1.isLow()) {
                        }

                    }

                    if (bits == 26) {
                        bits=0;

                        Print();

                    }

                }

            }
        });
        th.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        th.start();
        System.out.println("Thread start");

        for (;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    protected static void Print() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.write(s[i]);

        }
        System.out.println();
        bits = 0;

    }

}
```

and output:

```
10100100111111110110011011
10100100111111110110011011
10100100111111110110011011
10100100111111110110011011
10100100111111110001101110
10010011111111011001101110
10010011111111011001101110
10010011111111011001101110
10010011111111011001101110
10010011111111011001101110
10010011111111011001101110
```

Answer (score 1):

Your printf statements may be causing the problem. Try storing the data and printing it at the end. printf tends to be slow (it involves several context switches).

Also, it seems you have no way of detecting if you miss a bit. I would say try a timeout, so if you don't get 26 bits in time reset your counter. That way you're not looping around reading nothing, and eventually getting misaligned data.

Comment: I have changed now my code to Java. It is doing the same thing

Comment: Same issue -- i suggest adding a timeout (or some other synchronization mechanism) inside your while loop. Misalignment seems almost a certainty with this code.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in C and python on a pi and also on an arduino. From my experience as @woodrow douglas says you need to capture the bits in a loop or use interrupts (better) and use a timeout which you increase each time you receive a bit and then print it out once you are sure you have all the bits (timed out).

This is how I do this on arduino using interrupts.

```
void zero(){
  bit_count ++; 
  bit_holder = (bit_holder << 1) + 0;  //shift left one and add a 0
  timeout = t;
}

void one(){
  bit_count ++; 
  bit_holder = (bit_holder << 1) + 1;  //shift left one and add a 1
  timeout = t;
}

void loop() {
  timeout --;
  if (timeout == 0 && bit_count > 0){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Dec:");
    lcd.print(bit_holder);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Hex:");
    lcd.print(String(bit_holder,HEX));

    Serial.print("bit count= "); 
    Serial.println(bit_count);
    Serial.print("bits= "); 
    Serial.println(bit_holder,BIN);
    oldbit = bit_holder;                //store previous this value as previous
    bit_count = 0;                     //reset bit count
    bit_holder = 0;      //reset badge number

  }

}
```

I never got any issues using C on Pi but I did get issues using python as it is not as real time. The only way it would work in Python was by using interrupts and I managed too get the bad read rate down to something like 1 in 200 but never completely remove it.

What I did in the end was use some C to collect the bits then call my python script with the bits for processing.

If you are interested this is the C code I use:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int r1data0 = 6; //pin 22
int r1data1 = 7; // Pin 7
// green goes to same as relay
int r1beep = 0;   //pin 11
int r2data0 = 10; /* P1-24 */
int r2data1 = 11; /* P1-26 */
//green goes to same as relay
int r2beep = 0;
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
//generic variables
int t = 5;
int blank; //blank variable to reset bits
int rel1time = 0;
int rel2time = 0;
int rel1 = 5;
int previoust;

//reader 1variables
int r1bits; // Collected bits storage area
int r1bit_count = 0; //to measure the size of bits
int oldr1bit_count = 0; //somewhere to store bitcount to send to python
int r1timeout; //timout to return correct value
char r1command[40];
int r1ret;

//reader 2 variables
int r2bits; // Collected bits storage area
int r2bit_count = 0; //to measure the size of bits
int oldr2bit_count = 0;
int r2timeout; //timout to return correct value
char r2command[40];

pthread_t threads;

void access_denied(int red){
    int pin;
    if(red = 1){pin = r1beep;}
    if(red = 2){pin = r2beep;}
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    delay(300);;
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
}

void *r1python_thread(void *val){
    sprintf(r1command,"python access.py  r1 %X %X", oldr1bit_count, val); //build python command
    FILE* file = popen(r1command, "r"); //execute command using popen    
    char buffer[5];
    fscanf(file, "%100s", buffer);  //read command output
    pclose(file);
    //printf("buffer is : %s\n", buffer);
    rel1time = atoi(buffer);  //convert returned string to int
    if(rel1time == 0){access_denied(1);}
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *r2python_thread(void *val){
    sprintf(r2command,"python access.py  r2 %X",val); //build python command
    FILE* file = popen(r2command, "r"); //execute command using popen    
    char buffer[5];
    fscanf(file, "%100s", buffer);  //read command output
    pclose(file);
    //printf("buffer is : %s\n", buffer);
    rel2time = atoi(buffer);  //convert returned string to int
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

//reader 1 bit functions
void onebit0(){ //adds a 0
        r1bit_count ++; //increase bit count
        r1bits = (r1bits << 1) + 0;
        r1timeout = t;   //reset timeout
}

void onebit1(){ //adds a 1
        r1bit_count ++; 
        r1bits = (r1bits << 1) + 1;
        r1timeout = t;   
}

//reader 2 bit functions
void twobit0(){ //adds a 0
        r2bit_count ++; //increase bit count
        r2bits = (r2bits << 1) + 0;
        r2timeout = t;   //reset timeout
}

void twobit1(){ //adds a 1
        r2bit_count ++; 
        r2bits = (r2bits << 1) + 1;
        r2timeout = t;   
}
int main(){
    wiringPiSetup(); //initialise wiringPi
    pinMode (r1data0, INPUT); // set reader 1 data0 as input
    pinMode (r1data1, INPUT); // set reader 1 data1 as input

    pinMode (r2data0, INPUT); // set reader 2 data0 as input
    pinMode (r2data1, INPUT); // set reader 2 data1 as input



    //reader 1
    wiringPiISR(r1data0, INT_EDGE_FALLING, onebit0); // set interrupt on data 0 if it falls call bit0 function
    wiringPiISR(r1data1, INT_EDGE_FALLING, onebit1); // set interrupt on data 1 if it falls call bit1 function
    //reader 2
    wiringPiISR(r2data0, INT_EDGE_FALLING, twobit0); // set interrupt on data 0 if it falls call bit0 function
    wiringPiISR(r2data1, INT_EDGE_FALLING, twobit1); // set interrupt on data 1 if it falls call bit1 function    

    while (1){ //loop
        if (r1bit_count > 0 ){ //if bits is not empty
            r1timeout--; // reduce timeout by 1
            if(r1timeout == 0){ //and it has timed out ie no more bits coming
                //printf("%X\n",r1bits);
                pthread_create(&threads, NULL, r1python_thread,(void *) r1bits); //start new thread for python program
                oldr1bit_count = r1bit_count;
                r1bit_count = 0; //reset bit count
                r1bits = blank; //clear bits cariable
                r1timeout = t; //reset timeout
                }
            }    
        if (r2bit_count > 0 ){ //if bits is not empty
            r2timeout--; // reduce timeout by 1
            if(r2timeout == 0){ //and it has timed out ie no more bits coming
                pthread_create(&threads, NULL, r2python_thread,(void *) r2bits); //start new thread for python program
                r2bit_count = 0; //reset bit count
                r2bits = blank; //clear bits cariable
                r2timeout = t; //reset timeout
                }
            }
        if (rel1time > 0){
            pinMode(rel1, OUTPUT);
            int diff = time(NULL) - previoust;
            if(diff >= 1){
            previoust = time(NULL);
            rel1time--;
            }
        }
        else{
            pinMode(rel1, INPUT);
            previoust = time(NULL);
        }
     delay(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```